# Populate input box with dates

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this two inputboxes that I want to populate by dates.

The first input box with an id of `start` must have today's date

then the other inputbox must have a date with 5 days interval from todays date

ex. `start` 5/02/2018 - 5/06/2018 `end`

```
<input type='text' class='input-sm form-control text-center' id='start'  name='start' />
<input type='text' class='input-sm form-control text-center ' id='end' name='end' />
```

Comment: you must have tried something no ?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey i haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: we are waiting @Corvus

Comment: @Corvus you should try it first and then post here if you've any issues in your attempt and everybody will be much happy to help :)

Comment: Try using some javascript `let now = new Date()` to get today. See the [docs for Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to fill dates in textbox, first of all set the id of textbox and then assign the value in textbox using jquery

```
 <div>
<input type="text" id="txt1">
<input type="text" id="txt2">
</div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth()+1;
var day = d.getDate();
var day5=d.getDate()+4;
var year=d.getFullYear();
var _CurrDate=month+'/'+day+'/'+year
var _NextDate=month+'/'+day5+'/'+year
$('#txt1').val(_CurrDate)
$('#txt2').val(_NextDate)

 });
 </script>
```